# WSL with VS Code: Why doesn't VS Code see my WSL installation?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have successfully installed Ubuntu with wsl.  I then installed VS Code and tried to browse for the directory on Ubuntu that contains a dummy project.  It doesn't see WSL/Ubuntu at all but I can open it in Sublime Text.  When installing VS Code I wasn't given any option to add to path so I assume there's no issue there.  Tried `code .` in my project directory and that didn't work, just got an error, command not found.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong, just don't know what.

Why doesn't VS Code see my WSL installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.) Make sure that you have installed the extension "Remote - WSL" in VSC.

2.) Make sure that the WSL is really installed.

3.) Open VSC and press the green "> <" in the lower left corner.

4.) Then press "New WSL Window using Distro".

5.) Choose your distro, (Ubtuntu, Debian, Kali etc)

6.) If everything worked, you should see "WSL: Debian" in the bottom left corner, or whatever you have chosen

Comment: I tried searching for the remote development extension yesterday and couldn't find it.  I'm looking in `Extensions > Manage Extensions` and searching for it.  Any ideas?

Comment: @user1532669 did you look for right here?

(https://prnt.sc/86zkfS4BKOHw)

Comment: @user1532669 If it helps you, here is the ID of the extension `(ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl)`

Comment: This is what I see on my VS Code:  https://prnt.sc/AI727icbmpy4

Comment: Oh, it all makes sense now. What you have there. Is VS (Visual Studio), but what you're talking about is VSC (Visual Studio Code). Those are two different proramms.

Comment: This is VS code (https://prnt.sc/40SctWvLa6zc), you have VS.

Comment: How annoying!  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If you haven't installed it yet, go ahead and install that. And follow my list (above). (https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Comment: As a tip for you, Visual Studio Code is a code editor, like Notepad++. On the other side, Visual Studio is an IDE. (IDE stands for integrated development environment)

Even if the unfortunately have almost the same names, they are more or less completely different.

Comment: Thank you.  Think I've just been away from development for too long!

Comment: Got it all working now.  Just had to install VS Code and install the extension.  Spent ages on this yesterday lol

Comment: Everything is fine, that's what the website was created for :) Ur welcome.